# Manage manualy Rails router for SOE and multilingual

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, uri, multilingual, rails-routing

I'm a beginner with Rails, and I ready all this [very usefull tutoriel (French)](http://french.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning) But I have some other question..

I learn how the basic Rails router works (based from Controller name) :

```
Requête   HTTP           URL Action 
-----------------------------------
GET       /users         index  
GET       /users/1       show   
GET       /users/new     new    
POST      /users         create 
GET       /users/1/edit  edit   
PUT       /users/1       update 
DELETE    /users/1       destroy
```

But I want make some modifications :

**1/ SOE**

I need to update route for user retrieve (show, update, ..) and i want use @user[:username] on URI instead of @user[:id]

So in my case : **/users/arthur** instead of **/users/1**

**2/ Multilingual**

On the same type of problem, i want add one the start of the URI the ISO code for each country (ex : /fr/users/) and create alias on my URI.

For example, before the Rails router was initialized I want update all routes like :

```
/utilisateurs/...  ->  /users/...
/produits/... -> /products/...
```

Can I do it easly ?! And these changes may be applicable by the `link_to` function ?

So if i'm call `like_to @user` ( with @user data : {'name'=>'arthur', 'lang'=>'fr'} ) the function should return **/fr/utilisateurs/arthur** instead of **/users/1**

Thank you all for helping !

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Translated Paths* for the multilingual definitions found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths). As for the use of `username` for the param you can follow [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-vanity-urls-in-rails), basically you override `to_param` and that will be used to generate the url when using `link_to` and other helpers.